# Run time error 1004, in my macro loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Declare Variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim AmQ As Worksheet, UpIss As Worksheet, QuMa As Worksheet

'Set your sheet names into variables for easier referencing
Set AmQ = Sheets("AMEND QUOTE")
Set UpIss = Sheets("UPISSUE")

For i = 7 To 57 '7 = Column H, 8 = Column G, etc.

'Set the address of the found value to the rng variable
Set rng = UpIss.Cells.Find(What:=AmQ.Cells(4, i).Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'CHECK IF THE SEARCH TERM (FROM QUOTE SHEET) WAS FOUND IN THE TARGET SHEET (ESTIMATE)

    If Not rng = "" Then 'CHECK IF THE SEARCH TERM WAS A ZERO LENGTH STRING

    rng.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0)).Copy 'Copy the cell 41 rows down and 3 columns across
        'QuMa.Cells(4, i).Offset(14, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Paste into the cell 14 rows below the original search term in the QUOTE sheet

        Sheets("QUOTE MASTER").Select
Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

'Copy Formats
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
'Copy Values
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True

'Autofit
Columns("C:Q").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.CutCopyMode = False



    ElseIf rng = "" Then 'EXIT SUB IF SEARCH TERM WAS A ZERO LENGTH STRING
        'MsgBox "Work is Done"
        Exit Sub
    End If

ElseIf rng Is Nothing Then 'EXIT SUB IF SEARCH TERM WAS NOT FOUND IN THE TARGET SHEET
    'MsgBox "Work is Done"
    Exit Sub

End If

Set rng = Nothing

Next i 'Move to the next column across and loop
```

This is where I am getting my error:

```
rng.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0)).Copy
```

not able to copy in the loop.

Comment: Try not to select cells when working with them - just reference them.  Rather than `rng.Offset(1, 0).Select Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(14, 0)).Copy` you could use `rng.Offset(1).Resize(14).Copy`

Comment: `Sub Test(): Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveCell: rng.Offset(1).Resize(14).Copy: With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QUOTE MASTER").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1): .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats: .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues: End With: End Sub` - not sure of formatting in comments, but this will copy/paste special without selecting the cells.  Have added **:** so it can be pasted on a single line and still work.